# Avoid ovrelapping of points in technology radar

Tags: d3.js, radar-chart

I am creating my own technology radar, for this I have downloaded the code from : https://github.com/trecenti/tech-radar

I have customized it as per my needs. In this I have modified "tech-radar.min.js" file to make it as per my requirements.

Now, one thing I am still unable to modify that is overlapping of points in the circle. As per my study the placement of points are according to the title of the point and chance.integer function.

I want to modify in a way so that points will not overlap.

Code of my index file is :

```
<body>
  <div id="radar">
  </div>
  <div id="ref-table"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var adopt = new tr.models.Cycle('Adopt', 0);
  var trial = new tr.models.Cycle('Trial', 1);
  var assess = new tr.models.Cycle('Assess', 2);
  var hold = new tr.models.Cycle('Hold', 3);

  var radar = new tr.models.Radar();
  var toolsQuadrant = new tr.models.Quadrant('Tools');
  var techniquesQuadrant = new tr.models.Quadrant('Techniques');
  var platformsQuadrant = new tr.models.Quadrant('Platforms');
  var languageFramework = new tr.models.Quadrant('Languages & Frameworks');

  toolsQuadrant.add([

      new tr.models.Blip('D3', adopt),
      new tr.models.Blip('Dependency Management for JavaScript', adopt, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Ansible', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Calabash', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Chaos Monkey', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Gatling', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Grunt.js', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Hystrix', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Icon fonts', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Librarian-puppet and Librarian-Chef', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Logstash & Graylog2', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Moco', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('PhantomJS', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Prototype On Paper', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('SnapCI', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Snowplow Analytics & Piwik', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Cloud-init', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Docker', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Octopus', assess),
      new tr.models.Blip('Sensu', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Travis for OSX/iOS', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Visual regression testing tools', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Xamarin', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Ant', hold, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Heavyweight test tools', hold),
      new tr.models.Blip('TFS', hold)
  ]);
  techniquesQuadrant.add([
      new tr.models.Blip('Capturing client-side JavaScript errors', adopt),
      new tr.models.Blip('Continuous delivery for mobile devices', adopt),
      new tr.models.Blip('Mobile testing on mobile networks', adopt),
      new tr.models.Blip('Segregated DOM plus node for JS Testing', adopt, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Windows infrastructure automation', adopt),
      new tr.models.Blip('Capture domain events explicitily', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Client and server rendering with same code', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('HTML5 storage instead of cookies', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Instrument all the things', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Masterless Chef/Puppet', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Micro-services', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Perimeterless enterprise', trial),
      new tr.models.Blip('Provisioning testing', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Structured logging', trial, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Bridging physical and digital worlds with simple hardware', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Collaborative analytics and data science', assess),
      new tr.models.Blip('Datensparsamkeit', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Development environments in the cloud', assess),
      new tr.models.Blip('Focus on mean time to recovery', assess),
      new tr.models.Blip('Machine image as a build artifact', assess),
      new tr.models.Blip('Tangible interaction', assess, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Cloud lift and shift', hold, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Ignoring OWASP Top 10', hold, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Siloed metrics', hold, true),
      new tr.models.Blip('Velocity as productivity', hold, true)

  ]);
  platformsQuadrant.add([
      new tr.models.Blip('Elastic Search', adopt),

  ]);
  languageFramework.add([
      new tr.models.Blip('Clojure', adopt, true),

  ]);

  radar.setFirstQuadrant(toolsQuadrant);
  radar.setSecondQuadrant(techniquesQuadrant);
  radar.setThirdQuadrant(platformsQuadrant);
  radar.setFourthQuadrant(languageFramework);

  var radarGraph = new tr.graphing.Radar(1080, radar);
  radarGraph.init('#radar').plot();
  var refTable = new tr.graphing.RefTable(radar);
  refTable.init('#ref-table').render();
</script>
```

and tech-radar.min.js file is :

```
var tr = tr || {};
tr.models = {}, tr.graphing = {}, tr.util = {}, tr.graphing.Radar = function(t, n) {
    function r() {
        return Math.round(t / 2)
    }

    function e() {
        p.append("line").attr("x1", r()).attr("y1", 0).attr("x2", r()).attr("y2", t).attr("stroke-width", 14), p.append("line").attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", r()).attr("x2", t).attr("y2", r()).attr("stroke-width", 14)
    }

    function a(t, n) {

        var e = (l.sequence(t.length), l.sum(t.length)),
            a = l.sum(n);
        return r() - r() * a / e
    }


    function u(t) {
        t.forEach(function(n, e) {
            p.append("circle").attr("cx", r()).attr("cy", r()).attr("r", a(t, e))
        })
    }

    function c(t) {
        var n;
        n = Math.round(r() / t.length), t.forEach(function(n, e) {
            p.append("text").attr("class", "line-text").attr("stroke", "#000000").attr("stroke-width", "0.3").attr("y", r() + 4).attr("x", r() - a(t, e) + 10).text(n.name()), p.append("text").attr("class", "line-text").attr("stroke", "#000000").attr("stroke-width", "0.3").attr("y", r() + 4).attr("x", r() + a(t, e) - 10).attr("text-anchor", "end").text(n.name())
        })
    }

    function o(t, n, r, e) {
        var a, u, c, o, i, s;
        return a = 13, u = n - a, c = t - a + 1, o = t + a + 1, i = n + a - a / 2.5, s = t + 1 + "," + u + " " + c + "," + i + " " + o + "," + i, (e || p).append("polygon").attr("points", s).attr("class", r).attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    }

    function i(t, n, r, e) {
        return (e || p).append("circle").attr("cx", t).attr("cy", n).attr("class", r).attr("stroke-width", 1.5).attr("r", 10)
    }

    function s(t, n, e, u, c) {
        var s;
        s = n.blips(), t.forEach(function(n, f) {
            var d, l, I;
            d = a(t, f), l = f == t.length - 1 ? 0 : a(t, f + 1);

            var I = s.filter(function(t) {
                return t.cycle() == n
            });

            I.forEach(function(t) {
                var a, s, f = t.name().split(""),
                    I = f.reduce(function(t, n) {
                        return t + n.charCodeAt(0)
                    }, 0);

                     /*var randomNumber = chance.integer({
                    min: 7,
                    max: 42
                });

                    var evenNumber = randomNumber * 2;
                    console.log(evenNumber);*/

                chance = new Chance(I * n.name().length * t.number()), a = Math.PI * chance.integer({
                    min: 13,
                    max: 85
                }) / 180, s = chance.floating({
                    min: l + 25,
                    max: d - 10
                });

                var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u,
                    v = p.append("g").attr("class", "blip-group").attr("id","diagram"+t.number()).attr("onmouseover", "mouseoverfunction("+t.number()+")").attr("onmouseout", "mouseoutfunction("+t.number()+")");
                t.isNew() ? o(m, y, c, v) : i(m, y, c, v), h.push(function() {
                   /* var n;
                    n = p.append("div").attr("x", m + 15).attr("y", y + 4).attr("class", "blip-name").attr("text-anchor", "left").text(t.name()), v.on("mouseover", function() {
                        n.style("display", "block")
                    }).on("mouseout", function() {
                        n.style("display", "none")
                    })*/

                     document.body.innerHTML +='<div class="d3-tip blip-name" id='+t.number()+' style="position:absolute;top:'+(y-15)+'px;left:'+m+'px;">'+t.name()+'</div>';
                }), v.append("text").attr("x", m).attr("y", y + 4).attr("id","point"+t.number()).attr("class", "blip-text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(t.number())
            })
        })
    }

    function f(n) {
        function r(t, n, r, e, a) {
            p.append("text").attr("x", r).attr("y", e).attr("class", a).attr("text-anchor", n).text(t)
        }
        r(n.I.name(), "end", t - 10, 10, "first"), r(n.II.name(), "start", 10, 10, "second"), r(n.III.name(), "start", 10, t - 10, "third"), r(n.IV.name(), "end", t - 10, t - 10, "fourth")
    }
    var d, l, p, h;
    return h = [], l = new tr.util.Fib, d = {}, d.svg = function() {
        return p
    }, d.init = function(t) {
        return p = d3.select(t || "body").append("svg"), d
    }, d.plot = function() {
        var r, a;
        r = n.cycles().reverse(), a = n.quadrants(), p.attr("width", t).attr("height", t), u(r), e(), c(r), n.hasQuadrants() && (f(a), s(r, a.I, 1, -1, "first"), s(r, a.II, -1, -1, "second"), s(r, a.III, -1, 1, "third"), s(r, a.IV, 1, 1, "fourth")), h.forEach(function(t) {
            t()
        })
    }, d
}, tr.graphing.RefTable = function(t) {
    function n() {
        var n = {};
        t.cycles().map(function(t) {
            return {
                order: t.order(),
                name: t.name()
            }
        }).sort(function(t, n) {
            return t.order === n.order ? 0 : t.order < n.order ? -1 : 1
        }).forEach(function(t) {
            n[t.name] = []
        });
        var r = [],
            e = t.quadrants();
        return Object.keys(e).forEach(function(t) {
            r = r.concat(e[t].blips())
        }), r.forEach(function(t) {
            n[t.cycle().name()].push(t)
        }), n
    }
    var r, e = {};
    return e.init = function(t) {
        return r = document.querySelector(t || "body"), e
    }, e.render = function() {
        var t = n(),
            /*e = '<table class="radar-ref-table">';
        Object.keys(t).forEach(function(n) {
            e += '<tr class="radar-ref-status-group"><td colspan="3">' + n + "</td></tr>", t[n].forEach(function(t) {

                var newValue = t.isNew();
                if(newValue==true){
                    var newText = '<span class="newText" style="background-color: rgba(179,32,89,.3);color: #0000;padding: 0 4px;border-radius: 2px; margin-left: 3px;">new</span>';
                }else{
                   var newText = ''; 
                }

                e += "<tr onmouseover='mouseoverfunction("+t.number()+")' onmouseout='mouseoutfunction("+t.number()+")' onclick='onclickfunction("+t.number()+")' id=table"+t.number()+"><td>" + t.number() + "</td><td>" + t.name() + newText +"</td></tr>"
                e += "<tr class='description-row' id=description"+t.number()+" style='display:none;'><td style='border-top:1px solid;'>&nbsp;</td><td style='border-top:1px solid;'>" + t.description() + "</td></tr>"
            })
        }), 

        e += "</table>", r.innerHTML = e*/
        e = '<div class="radar-ref-table accordion">';
        Object.keys(t).forEach(function(n) {
            if(n=='Adopt'){
                tooltipText = 'Abopt description';
            }
            if(n=='Trial'){
                tooltipText = 'Trial description';
            }
            if(n=='Assess'){
                tooltipText = 'Assess description';
            }
            if(n=='Hold'){
                tooltipText = 'Hold description';
            }
            e += '<div class="radar-ref-status-group">' + n + "<div class='tooltip'><span class='tooltip-icon'>?</span><span class='tooltiptext'>"+tooltipText+"</span></div></div>", t[n].forEach(function(t) {
                var newValue = t.isNew();
                if(newValue=='true'){
                    var newText = '<span class="newText" style="background-color: rgba(179,32,89,.3);color: #0000;padding: 0 4px;border-radius: 2px; margin-left: 3px;">new</span>';
                }else{
                   var newText = ''; 
                }
                e += "<div onmouseover='mouseoverfunction("+t.number()+")' onmouseout='mouseoutfunction("+t.number()+")' id=table"+t.number()+"><a class='accordion-section-title' href='#accordion-"+t.number()+"'>"+t.number()+ ". " + t.name() + newText +"</a>"
                e += "<div id='accordion-"+t.number()+"' class='accordion-section-content   '><p>"+t.description()+"</p></div></div>"
            })
        }), 

        e += "</div>", r.innerHTML = e
    }, e
}, tr.models.Blip = function(t, n, r, e) {
    var a, u;
    return a = {}, u = -1, a.name = function() {
        return t
    }, a.description = function() {
        return e || ""
    }, a.isNew = function() {
        return r
    }, a.cycle = function() {
        return n
    }, a.number = function() {
        return u
    }, a.setNumber = function(t) {
        u = t
    }, a
}, tr.models.Cycle = function(t, n) {
    var r = {};
    return r.name = function() {
        return t
    }, r.order = function() {
        return n
    }, r
}, tr.models.Quadrant = function(t) {
    var n, r;
    return n = {}, r = [], n.name = function() {
        return t
    }, n.add = function(t) {
        Array.isArray(t) ? r = r.concat(t) : r.push(t)
    }, n.blips = function() {
        return r.slice(0)
    }, n
}, tr.models.Radar = function() {
    function t(t) {
        t.forEach(function(t) {
            t.setNumber(++u)
        })
    }

    function n() {
        var t = [];
        for (var n in a) a.hasOwnProperty(n) && null != a[n] && t.push(a[n]);
        return t
    }

    function r() {
        return n().reduce(function(t, n) {
            return t.concat(n.blips())
        }, [])
    }
    var e, a, u;
    return u = 0, a = {
        I: null,
        II: null,
        III: null,
        IV: null
    }, e = {}, e.setFirstQuadrant = function(n) {
        a.I = n, t(a.I.blips())
    }, e.setSecondQuadrant = function(n) {
        a.II = n, t(a.II.blips())
    }, e.setThirdQuadrant = function(n) {
        a.III = n, t(a.III.blips())
    }, e.setFourthQuadrant = function(n) {
        a.IV = n, t(a.IV.blips())
    }, e.hasQuadrants = function() {
        return !!(a.I || a.II || a.III || a.IV)
    }, e.cycles = function() {
        var t, n;
        n = [], t = {}, r().forEach(function(n) {
            t[n.cycle().name()] = n.cycle()
        });
        for (var e in t) t.hasOwnProperty(e) && n.push(t[e]);
        return n.slice(0).sort(function(t, n) {
            return t.order() - n.order()
        })
    }, e.quadrants = function() {
        return a
    }, e
}, tr.util.Fib = function() {
    var t = {};
    return t.sequence = function(t) {
        for (var n = [0, 1], r = 2; t > r; r++) n[r] = n[r - 2] + n[r - 1];
        return n
    }, t.sum = function(n) {
        return 0 === n ? 0 : 1 === n ? 1 : t.sequence(n + 1).reduce(function(t, n) {
            return t + n
        }, 0)
    }, t
};
```

If somebody have the idea about that code, please help me to avoid this overlapping. As I am not a javascript expert, an expert can solve it.

You can download the code from https://github.com/trecenti/tech-radar . Just run the index.html file which is inside example folder in your browser and try avoiding the overlapping of points.

It will be a great as I have already spent too many hours on it but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the JS file to avoid overlapping of points. To do this just open your "tech-radar.min.js" file and file the below code :

```
d = a(t, f), l = f == t.length - 1 ? 0 : a(t, f + 1);

            var I = s.filter(function(t) {
                return t.cycle() == n
            });

            I.forEach(function(t) {
                var a, s, f = t.name().split(""),
                    I = f.reduce(function(t, n) {
                        return t + n.charCodeAt(0)
                    }, 0);

                     /*var randomNumber = chance.integer({
                    min: 7,
                    max: 42
                });

                    var evenNumber = randomNumber * 2;
                    console.log(evenNumber);*/

                chance = new Chance(I * n.name().length * t.number()), a = Math.PI * chance.integer({
                    min: 13,
                    max: 85
                }) / 180, s = chance.floating({
                    min: l + 25,
                    max: d - 10
                });

                var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u,
```

Now, replace the above code with the below mentioned :

```
//new variables for workaround solution - BEGIN
            aa = 0, bb = 0, cc = 0, dd = 0,
            aa1 = 1, bb1 = 1, cc1 = 1, dd1 = 1,
            ee = 0, ff = 0, gg = 0, hh = 0, 
            ee1 = 1, ff1 = 1, gg1 = 1, hh1 = 1,
            ii = 0, jj = 0, kk = 0, ll = 0, 
            ii1 = 1, jj1 = 1, kk1 = 1, ll1 = 1,
            oo = 0, pp = 0, qq = 0, rr = 0,
            oo1 = 1, pp1 = 1, qq1 = 1, rr1 = 1,

            xy1 = 20,  xy2 = 20, xy3 = 30, xy4 = 50, 
            xy5 = 20, xy6 = 40, xy7 = 30, xy8 = 50, 
            xy9 = 50, xy10 = 40, xy11 = 30, xy12 = 50, 
            xy13 = 50, xy14 = 40, xy15 = 30, xy16 = 50,
            yz1 = 300, yz2 = 250, yz3 = 250, yz4 = 200;
            //new variables for workaround solution - END

            d = a(t, f), l = f == t.length - 1 ? 10 : a(t, f + 1);



            var I = s.filter(function(t) {
                return t.cycle() == n
            });


            //New loop - BEGIN
            I.forEach(function(t) {

                if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    aa = aa + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    bb = bb + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    cc = cc + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    dd = dd + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    ee = ee + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    ff = ff + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    gg = gg + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    hh = hh + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    ii = ii + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    jj = jj + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    kk = kk + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    ll = ll + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    oo = oo + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    pp = pp + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    qq = qq + 1;
                }
                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    rr = rr + 1;
                }                       
            })              
            //New loop - END




            I.forEach(function(t) {

                var a, s, f = t.name().split(""),
                    I = f.reduce(function(t, n) {
                        return t + n.charCodeAt(0)
                    }, 0);          


                // New conditional statements - BEGIN



                if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    if (aa1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (aa1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (aa1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }                   
                    a = xy1 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy1 = xy1 + (yz1 / aa);     
                    aa1 = aa1 + 1;  
                    if (aa1 > 3)
                    {
                        aa1 = 1;
                    }
                }

                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    if (bb1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (bb1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (bb1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }                   
                    a = xy2 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy2 = xy2 + (yz2 / bb); 
                    bb1 = bb1 + 1;  
                    if (bb1 > 3)
                    {
                        bb1 = 1;
                    }                   
                }

                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    if (cc1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (cc1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (cc1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy3 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy3 = xy3 + (yz2 / cc); 
                    cc1 = cc1 + 1;  
                    if (cc1 > 3)
                    {
                        cc1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "first" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    if (dd1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (dd1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (dd1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy4 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy4 = xy4 + (yz4 / dd);     
                    dd1 = dd1 + 1;  
                    if (dd1 > 3)
                    {
                        dd1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    if (ee1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (ee1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (ee1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy5 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy5 = xy5 + (yz1 / ee);
                    ee1 = ee1 + 1;  
                    if (ee1 > 3)
                    {
                        ee1 = 1;
                    }   

                }

                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    if (ff1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (ff1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (ff1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy6 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy6 = xy6 + (yz2/ ff);  
                    ff1 = ff1 + 1;  
                    if (ff1 > 3)
                    {
                        ff1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    if (gg1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (gg1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (gg1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy7 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy7 = xy7 + (yz3 / gg);
                    gg1 = gg1 + 1;  
                    if (gg1 > 3)
                    {
                        gg1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "second" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    if (hh1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (hh1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (hh1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy8 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy8 = xy8 + (yz4 / hh);
                    hh1 = hh1 + 1;  
                    if (hh1 > 3)
                    {
                        hh1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    if (ii1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (ii1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (ii1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy9 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy9 = xy9 + (yz1 / ii);
                    ii1 = ii1 + 1;  
                    if (ii1 > 3)
                    {
                        ii1 = 1;
                    }   

                }

                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    if (jj1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (jj1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (jj1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy10 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy10 = xy10 + (yz2 / jj);
                    jj1 = jj1 + 1;  
                    if (jj1 > 3)
                    {
                        jj1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    if (kk1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (kk1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (kk1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy11 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy11 = xy11 + (yz3 / kk);
                    kk1 = kk1 + 1;  
                    if (kk1 > 3)
                    {
                        kk1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "third" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    if (ll1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (ll1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (ll1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy12 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy12 = xy12 + (yz4 / ll);
                    ll1 = ll1 + 1;  
                    if (ll1 > 3)
                    {
                        ll1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Hold")
                {
                    if (oo1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (oo1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (oo1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy13 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy13 = xy13 + (yz1 / oo);
                    oo1 = oo1 + 1;  
                    if (oo1 > 3)
                    {
                        oo1 = 1;
                    }   

                }

                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Assess")
                {
                    if (pp1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 10;
                    }   
                    else if (pp1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (pp1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 10;
                    }               
                    a = xy14 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy14 = xy14 + (yz2 / pp);
                    pp1 = pp1 + 1;  
                    if (pp1 > 3)
                    {
                        pp1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Trial")
                {
                    if (qq1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (qq1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (qq1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy15 / 180;             
                    m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy15 = xy15 + (yz3 / qq) ;
                    qq1 = qq1 + 1;  
                    if (qq1 > 3)
                    {
                        qq1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }

                else if (c == "fourth" && n.name()== "Adopt")
                {
                    if (rr1 == 1)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) + 30;
                    }   
                    else if (rr1 == 2)
                    {
                        s = (l + d) / 2; 
                    }

                    else if (rr1 == 3)
                    {
                        s = ((l + d) / 2) - 30;
                    }               
                    a = xy16 / 180;
                    var m = r() + s * Math.cos(a) * e,
                    y = r() + s * Math.sin(a) * u;
                    xy16 = xy16 + (yz4 / rr);
                    rr1 = rr1 + 1;  
                    if (rr1 > 3)
                    {
                        rr1 = 1;
                    }                       
                }
```

Once you replace the code as mentioned above, just look at the points they are not overlapping to each other.

This is a lengthy approach, anyone can optimize it but it will solve the overlapping issue.

I am using the above mentioned approach which can help someone to get rid of this overlapping. But if anybody has an idea of any other better approach to avoid this overlapping, please share.

Thanks